# Can't use Background-image html/css

Tags: html, css, image

This is now the complete html/CSS because someone aked for it.

This is an updated version but it still does not work! I run this on a localhost (usbwebserver).

I am trying to use a background-image for a div but it will not show the image.The image is in the Images file.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


    <title>Computing</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/CSS.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/laptop.ico" />

</head>

<header class="Header">
<div class="logo" onClick="location.href='Home.html'"> </div>

    <h1>Computing</h1>

</header>

<body>


            <div class="opvulling1"></div>
            <div class="buttonA">Home</div>
            <div class="button" onClick="location.href='Laptops.php'">Laptops</div>
            <div class="button" onClick="location.href='Cameras.php'">Camera's</div>
            <div class="button" onClick="location.href='gsms.php'">GSM's</div>
            <div class="button" onClick="location.href='Contact.html'">Contact</div>
            <div class="button" onClick="location.href='Winkelwagen.php'">Winkelwagen</div>
            <div class="opvulling2"></div>


<div class="Central">
    <section>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed lacus augue, aliquam ut gravida eget, adipiscing in elit. Suspendisse potenti. Integer laoreet, risus nec fermentum imperdiet, leo magna interdum eros, eu aliquam turpis risus eget nulla. Vivamus ultrices urna vitae nisl vestibulum cursus. Suspendisse sed gravida libero. Fusce blandit dui id porttitor sodales. Morbi vitae sapien quis nulla gravida dignissim. Donec pharetra ipsum tellus, sed laoreet dui viverra in. Nullam blandit diam ac quam consectetur consectetur. Nulla facilisi. Nam ut quam diam. Nunc nec nisl ut tortor luctus commodo. Fusce nec velit neque. Vivamus ac dui tempor, malesuada lacus sed, sollicitudin odio. Nullam ac adipiscing velit, sed dapibus mauris. Sed et egestas dolor.</section>

    <section>Phasellus non interdum nisl. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi sed convallis nisi. In in tellus eleifend, tincidunt metus et, auctor mauris. Nullam risus libero, condimentum in adipiscing elementum, tincidunt ut elit. Sed eu diam sed erat aliquam convallis in a mauris. Cras at enim condimentum dolor consequat consequat. Nulla mattis leo in justo molestie, nec tincidunt nulla consequat. Duis accumsan congue lacus sit amet vehicula. Duis vitae pretium urna. Donec sodales, risus id auctor tempor, nisi nisi vehicula dui, in aliquam ante arcu sit amet dui. Curabitur fringilla cursus erat, id lobortis neque aliquet a. Etiam et pharetra diam.</section>
</div>
```

css:

```
body{

background-color:#CAEAED;

}
.logo{
background-image:url('Images/Computing.jpg');
height:100px;
width:200px;



}

.Central{
background-color: #FFFFFF;
width: 50%;
margin-top: 50px;

margin-left:20%;
height: auto;
padding: 1%;

font-family:Arial;
font-size: 16px;




}
.Header{
background-color: #CAEAED;

margin-top:-10px;
margin-left:-10px;

width: 101%;
position:relative;  

height: 5%;
padding-top:1px;
padding-right: 1%;

text-align:center;

}

h1{
font-size:30px;
font-family:Arial;
text-align: center;

}
section{
padding: 1%;
}

.button{
background-color:#009999;
font-family:Arial;
font-size: 16px;
position:relative;
float:left;

margin-top: 2px;
margin-right:2px;
height:20px;
padding:5px;
}
.buttonA{
font-family:Arial;
font-size: 16px;
background-color:#015965;
transition: width 2s;
margin-top: 2px;
position:relative;
float:left;
margin-right:2px;
height:20px;
padding:5px;
}
.opvulling1{
background-color:#009999;

float:left;
margin-left:-10px;
margin-top: 2px;
margin-right:2px;
height:20px;
padding:5px;
width:20%;



}
.opvulling2{
background-color:#009999;

float:left;
margin-top: 2px;
margin-right:-2000px;
height:20px;
padding:5px;
width:1200px;

}
.button:hover{
cursor:pointer;
background-color:#1F6B75;
font-family:Arial;
font-size: 16px;
}



img{
height: 250px;
width: 300px;

}
h3{
font-family:Arial;

}

form{
float: left;
margin-left: 20px

}

td{
width:40%;
text-align:center;
}

.Prijs{
float:left;


}
.article{
position:relative;
float:left;
margin-right:20px;
background-color:white;



}



h2{
font-family:Arial;
}
```

How can I make the image work? I already searched it on the internet but i can't find it anywhere. Someone please help.

Comment: The `div` probably has no height. Try to set dimensions of this div or add some content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
background-image:url('../Images/Computing.jpg');
```

Your CSS is called in a relative way this requires you to specify your path relative to your CSS file.

Answer (score 3):

change `\` with `/`

```
 .logo{
      background-image:url('Images/Computing.jpg');
}
```

If you don't see the image try to put the dimension of the image for example if is 200*300 try this:

```
 .logo{
          width:200px;
          height:300px;
          background-image:url('Images/Computing.jpg');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a `backslash` instead of a regular `slash`.

```
background-image:url('Images\Computing.jpg');}
                            ^
                            ^

background-image:url('Images/Computing.jpg');}
```

This is supposed to work if the image is indeed in the specified location.

Comment: We need to see your HTML to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your site on Linux, you should be aware that on the server site, file names are case sensitive (Computing.jpg not equal computing.jpg). Pay attention the file name is same as the css reference.

Good luck!

Comment: Good call on the Computing vs computing i was thinking it might be the whole directory thought images vs Images

Answer (score 0):

you should use background-image style as

`.logo {
background-image:url('Images/computing.jpg');}`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone above about the slash, and that you need a width and height for the BG image but i see something else that might be causing the issue. Assuming that you are doing this on a web server and not locally. If this is a Linux environment then everything needs to be case sensitive. I have found that it is bad practice to use Images/ i would change to images/

Answer (score 0):

Write some text inside your logo div just to ensure that is not problem with the with and height of the div.